# Given an ANTLR ParserRuleContext, how do I find the first parent of a given type?

Tags: c#, antlr, antlr4

I'm using ANTLR's `XPath` to get database views' table dependencies:

```
//create_view//from_clause//tableview_name
```

Now I need to get the view name that each table name belongs to. E.g., if there were a `FirstParentOfType` method, the code might look like this:

```
context.FirstParentOfType<Create_viewContext>().tableview_name().GetText();
```

But that method doesn't exist as far as I can tell. How is this done?

Answer (score 0):

Pending a better way, here's an extension method that does it:

```
public static class RuleContextExtensions
{
    public static T FirstParentOfType<T>(this RuleContext context) where T : RuleContext => context as T ?? (context.Parent != null ? FirstParentOfType<T>(context.Parent) : null);
}
```